# PHP Xpath : get all href values that contain needle

Tags: php, xpath, href

Working with PHP Xpath trying to quickly pull certain links within a html page.

The following will find all href links on mypage.html:
`$nodes = $x->query("//a[@href]");`

Whereas the following will find all href links where the **description** matches my needle:
`$nodes = $x->query("//a[contains(@href,'click me')]");`

What I am trying to achieve is matching on the href itself, more specific finding url's that contain certain parameters. Is that possible within a Xpath query or should I just start manipulating the output from the first Xpath query?

Comment: Yes, but searching for 'needle' returns the text part in *$node->nodeValue();* and not the desired *http://example.com?param=needle* ...?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question correctly, but the second XPath expression already does what you are describing. It does not match against the text node of the A element, but the href attribute:

```
$html = <<< HTML
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://example.com/page?foo=bar">Description</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://example.com/page?lang=de">Description</a>
    </li>
</ul>
HTML;

$xml  = simplexml_load_string($html);
$list = $xml->xpath("//a[contains(@href,'foo')]");
```

Outputs:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["href"]=>
      string(31) "http://example.com/page?foo=bar"
    }
    [0]=>
    string(11) "Description"
  }
}
```

As you can see, the returned NodeList contains only the A element with href containing foo (which I understand is what you are looking for). It contans the entire element, because the XPath translates to *Fetch all A elements with href attribute containing foo*. You would then access the attribute with

```
echo $list[0]['href'] // gives "http://example.com/page?foo=bar"
```

If you only want to return the attribute itself, you'd have to do

```
//a[contains(@href,'foo')]/@href
```

Note that in SimpleXml, this would return a SimpleXml element though:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["href"]=>
      string(31) "http://example.com/page?foo=bar"
    }
  }
}
```

but you can output the URL now by

```
echo $list[0] // gives "http://example.com/page?foo=bar"
```

Comment: that is what I meant. Only my html document fails when using SimpleXML. The xpath query works though, and using it with DomXpath gives me what I want. Thanks!