# Extracting specific <a href> URLs out of the document

Tags: php, string, url, extract, preg-match

I think this should be elementary, but I still can't get my head around it.
Let's say there's fair amount of HTML documents and I need to catch every image URLs out of them.

The rest of the content changes, but the base of the url is always the same for example: `http://images.examplesite.com/images/`,

So I want to extract every string that contains that part. the problem is that they're always mixed with `<a href=''>` or `<img src=''>` tags, so how could I drop them out? `preg_match` probably?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Xpath : get all href values that contain needle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392393/php-xpath-get-all-href-values-that-contain-needle)

Comment: You can also use DOM as shown in [Preg_Match All A href](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519696/preg-match-all-a-href/1519791#1519791). Just change the XPath to the one given in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like: `preg_match_all('/http:\/\/images\.examplesite\.com\/images\/(.*?)"/i', $html_data, $results, PREG_SET_ORDER)`

Comment: wow, that was fast. it leaves one " after the string, but believe it or not I got rid of it myself ;D thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

or use regular expression.

```
  preg_match_all("/http:\/\/images.examplesite.com\/images\/(.*?)\"/s", $str, $preg);
  print_r($preg);
```